# Xcode 10, Value of type Anyobject has no member

Tags: swift

To be honest i don't know exactly what it should do but in Xcode 9 it works perfectly and on 10 i got these errors

```
open var x: Double { return _x }
    open var y: Double { return _y }
    open var xPx: CGFloat { return _xPx }
    open var yPx: CGFloat { return _yPx }
    open var dataSetIndex: Int { return _dataSetIndex }
    open var stackIndex: Int { return _stackIndex }
    open var axis: YAxis.AxisDependency { return _axis }

    open var isStacked: Bool { return _stackIndex >= 0 }
```

Sets the x- and y-position (pixels) where this highlight was last drawn.

```
open func setDraw(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        self.drawX = x
        self.drawY = y
    }
```

Sets the x- and y-position (pixels) where this highlight was last drawn.

```
open func setDraw(pt: CGPoint) {
        self.drawX = pt.x
        self.drawY = pt.y
    }

    open override var description: String
    {
        return "Highlight, x: \(_x), y: \(_y), dataIndex (combined charts): \(dataIndex), dataSetIndex: \(_dataSetIndex), stackIndex (only stacked barentry): \(_stackIndex)"
    }

open override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool
    {
        if object == nil
        {
            return false
        }

        if !(object! as AnyObject).isKind(of: type(of: self))
        {
            return false
        }

        if (object! as AnyObject).x != _x
        {
            return false
        }

        if (object! as AnyObject).y != _y
        {
            return false
        }

        if (object! as AnyObject).dataIndex != dataIndex      line1
        {
            return false
        }

        if (object! as AnyObject).datasetIndex != _dataSetIndex      line2
        {
            return false
        }

        if (object! as AnyObject).stackIndex != _stackIndex      line3
        {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```

The errors are in line1: Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'dataIndex'
line2: Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'dataIndex'
line3:Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'stackIndex'; did you mean 'tagAtIndex'?
Searched but didn't find any useful

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: I can't work out what this code is meant to do, but if you are trying to test if two objects are equivalent or the same why not use the existing `==` and `===` operators.  You may also need to research the `equatable` protocol to ensure the objects can be compared with these operators.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to translate a java solution into swift which is not a good idea, instead read up on the [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol

Comment: Maybe the edit explain it

Comment: I don't understand how your last edit improves the question, the error is quite clear. `AnyObject` is a protocol that all classes conform to, it has no properties what so ever and knows nothing about your custom types. So `dataIndex` and `stackIndex` can't be accessed from a variable of type `AnyObject`.The easiest solution is to conform to the `Equatable` protocol instead of using this `isEqual` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isEqual` method body is pretty *objective-c-ish*.

If you really need `isEqual` this is a *swiftier* syntax

```
open override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    guard let obj = object as? Self else { return false }
    return obj.x == x && obj.y == y && obj.dataIndex == dataIndex && obj.dataSetIndex == dataSetIndex && obj.stackIndex == stackIndex
}
```

Side note:

Don't use private backing properties starting with an underscore character in Swift at all. That's also a bad *objective-c-ish* legacy habit. If you need constants declare constants.